# Self-avoiding walks on strips

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, pr.probability, graph-theory

A *strip* is a locally finite graph which admits a quasi-transitive (i.e. finitley many orbits on vertices) action of $\mathbb Z$. A *self avoiding walk* is a walk which visits no vertex more than once.

Is it known that the random self-avoiding walk on any strip has positive speed? More precisely, let $W_n$ be a self avoiding walk of length $n$ chosen uniformly at random, and denote by $d_n$ the distance (in the graph metric) between the initial and terminal vertex of $W_n$. Are there $a,b>0$ such that $\operatorname P[d_n<an] < e^{-b n}$ for any large enough $n$?

Some special cases have been proven in "*Janson, Svante*, Random self-avoiding walks in some one-dimensional lattices, Ann. Discrete Math. 33, 91-109 (1987) [ZBL0674.05043](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0674.05043).", and more special cases can be proved along the same lines, but the proof does not immediately help with the general case.